# Merging branches with Pycharm using Github repo

Tags: github, version-control, merge, pycharm

### What is the correct way to merge two branches of a Git**hub** project with Pycharm?

Suppose there is a branch in a Github project called `master` and I clone the repo with Pycharm. After that, I create a new branch `dev` by using Pycharm. The new branch is then shown correctly on Github and some commits are made to the branch.

---

Now, I want to merge the changes from the `dev` branch to the `master` branch.

For ordinary git (not Github) projects, I would checkout to the local `master` in Pycharm, click on `dev` in the local branch and select the ***merge*** context menu. As a result, `dev` would be merged to `master` such that it can be safely deleted.Though, even after I merge the *local* `master` with the *remote* `master` branch, no changes are shown on Github and both branches still exist.

I also tried to close Pycharm, do a pull request on Github, merge the branches there and restart Pycharm. Unfortunately, Pycharm doesn't even recognize that the *remote* `dev` branch has been deleted.

---

My subpar solution has been as follows:

- Pycharm: Merge *local* `dev` to *local* `master`, delete *local* `dev`, merge *local*
  `master` with  *remote* `master`
- Github: Create PR, merge branches, delete `dev`
- Pycharm: Delete *remote* `dev`

Now, if I rebase onto the remote `master` in Pycharm, I get the correct merged branch. Unfortunately though, using the ***compare*** context menu, Pycharm still shows that the *remote* `master` compared to the *local* `master` doesn't have the commits from `dev`. Although a rebase from the *remote* `master` contains all the commits from `dev`...

Sadly, there's also no Pycharm manual for merging branches with Git**hub** (for normal git there is). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to manually push your branch merge as it seems that pycharm doesn't do this, but it thinks it has.

I've noticed the same issue and it seems that the merge is not pushed from the local copy. In a command shell I checkout the master branch of my project and it tells me that I am ahead of online repository, so to resolve this I issue the `git push` command and then when I check github it has been uploaded.

```
(tf36) E:\git\alpha-zero-theputernerd>git checkout master
Already on 'master'
A       src/alpha_zero/env/env_inherit_from.py
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

(tf36) E:\git\alpha-zero-theputernerd>git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/theputernerd/alpha-zero-theputernerd.git
   bb60325..37c3c9d  master -> master
```

Comment: Just to add for all GitHub newbies like me who are not so familiar with the command shell: as of Pycharm 2021.1, you can also do the final push within PyCharm instead of using the command shell. I merged my "dev" branch into the main branch by: checking out to the "main" branch, merging the "dev" into the "main". Now on Github, it says that the "dev" is ahead of the "main" branch. Now push from your local repo and the changes made in "dev" now appear in the "main" branch also on GitHub.