# Rebase/Merging individual files from one branche onto master with Pycharm using Github/Gitlab

Tags: git, merge, pycharm, rebase

Suppose there is a Git project with a branch called `master`  and I clone the repo with Pycharm. After that, I create a new branch `dev` using Pycharm. The new branch is then shown correctly on Gitlab and some commits are made to the branch.

Now, very similar to a previous post ([Merging branches with Pycharm using Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882411/merging-branches-with-pycharm-using-github-repo)), I would like to rebase changes from this branch to `master`. However not *all* of the changes, but only some files. In fact, I would like to just rebase/push one new file `newfile.py` created in `dev` onto `master`.

I assume, I have to somehow edit the answer of the aforementioned post to make this happen. I am not experienced in command-line git and couldn't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a guess: either make `dev` look exactly like what you want to merge into `master`, then do it, or, make a second branch that looks exactly like what you want to merge into `master` and then merge that branch in. Read up on `git rebase -i` to learn how to pick and choose subsets of your existing commits.